# Convert xls to csv and create/update InMemoryUploadedFile Django

Tags: python, django, excel, csv, xlrd

I am using xlrd and csv of python to parse xls to csv. When user uploads xls or xlsx file, I am able to parse and generate csv. Though it generates actual file, instead I want to update or create new InMemoryUploadFile object which I can use to create record with FileField object. Is there any way to do it? I tried to look for the examples, though most of the examples are for image files to InMemoryUploadFile.

Here is sample code I have tried -

```
    import csv
    import xlrd
    import StringIO
    from django.core.files.uploadedfile import InMemoryUploadedFile        
    .......
    .......

    #xls_file is excel file
    file_name = '%s.csv'%(xls_file.name)
    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=xls_file.read())
    all_worksheets = workbook.sheet_names()

    # for now starting with reading the first sheet
    worksheet_name = all_worksheets[0]
    worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_name(worksheet_name)

    csv_output = StringIO.StringIO()
    csv_data = []
    for rownum in xrange(worksheet.nrows):
        csv_data.append(
            [unicode(
                entry).encode("utf-8") for entry in worksheet.row_values(
                rownum)])
    writer = csv.writer(csv_output)
    for row in csv_data:
        writer.writerow(csv_data)

    csv_file = InMemoryUploadedFile(writer, None, file_name, 'text/csv',
                              None, 'utf-8')
    return csv_file
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to use ContentFile instead?

```
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
def save_file(csv_output):
    mymodel = MyModel.objects.get(id=1)
    file_content = ContentFile(csv_output.getvalue())
    mymodel.myfilefield.save(request.FILES['yourupload'].name, file_content)
```

Comment: The link to the original tutorial is dead.